# Am i constrained in what i can do with gmap in Primefaces?

Tags: javascript, java, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, primefaces

im new to prime faces and i was just wondering if it is possible to add custom google code to the prime faces gmap component. I was looking at the code given on the primefaces site , ie add marker etc, but i was wondering if i am constrained to these code functions on the site. Ideally i would prefer a map that allows a user to add multiple markers connected by poly-lines which would eventually meet up to form a polygon(ie created by the user via an interactive map) and eventyually get the area of the polygon, by using java-script, however i am only able to implement the given code on the prime-faces site(the code listed on this page(http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/d ... asic.xhtml). So am i constrainted to these functions or is there more customization options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an idea:

In the funtion called `init()` from this [**example**](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/gmap/polygons.xhtml), you can pass in an array of coordinates (these can come from markers that your users generate). And each time a marker is added, call `init()` so it creates a polygon for you using the markers' lat/lng info.

For calculating the area, you have to actually come up with a algorithm or function like [**this**](https://web.archive.org/web/20130301120148/http://geojason.info/demos/line-length-polygon-area-google-maps-v3) and implement it using Primefaces syntax. Or something that can be done by using ideas from the [**Geometry Library**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry).

Hope this gives you a starting point.

Comment: Thanks so_jin_ee, i used dependency injection to forward the markers bean values to the polygon bean, worked like a charm.